# Excel incorrectly converts Date into Int

Tags: sql-server, excel, date

I'm pulling the data from SQL database. I have a couple columns with date which need to be converted into Int type, but when I do this the date changes (-2 days). I tried Cast and Convert and it's always the same.
Converting to other type works fine and returns the correct date, but doesn't work for me. I need only the date part from datetime and it needs to be recognised as a date by Excel.

Why is this happening? Any ideas how to get it sorted?

I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT wotype3, CONVERT(INT,wo_date2 ,103), CAST(duedate AS int) FROM Tasks WHERE 
duedate > DATEADD(DAY,1, GETDATE()) 
AND wo_date2>0
AND wo_date2<DATEADD(WEEK,3,GETDATE())
ORDER BY wotype3
```

Comment: have a look at `"CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, wo_date2/1440, start_date_in_your_database))`

Comment: how you are exporting data into excel file?

Comment: Pratik: I'm using SQL Server connection from Data tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server 2008 and above, you can use the DATE datatype.

```
declare @dt datetime = '12/24/2013 10:45 PM'  -- some date for example
SELECT @dt as OriginalDateTime, CAST(@dt as DATE) as OnlyDate
```

For versions prior to SQL Server 2008, you would need to truncate the time part using one or the other functions. Here is one way to do that:

```
declare @dt datetime = '12/24/2013 10:45 PM'  -- some date for example
SELECT @dt as OriginalDateTime, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@dt AS FLOAT)) as DATETIME) as OnlyDate
```

Comment: Trunctating is the answer! In Excel 2010 Datetime field is treated as a number, but Date - not, that's why I couldn't use it. Converting to Int rounds the Datetime to the next integer, so the values were incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

I've had big problems with this, checking my SQL Server's calculation results with "expected results" which a user had created using Excel.

We had discrepancies just because of this 2-day date difference.

Why does it happen ?

Two reasons:

1. SQL Server uses a *zero-based* date count from Jan 1 1900, but Excel uses a 1-based date count from Jan 1 1900.
2. Excel has a bug in it (gasp!) which makes it think that the year 1900 was a leap year.  It wasn't.  SQL Server correctly refuses to let you have a date value containing "`29-Feb-1900`".

[image]

Combine these two discrepancies, and this is why all dates, from March 1 1900 onwards, are always 2-days out.

Apparently, this Excel bug is a known issue, to keep it in line with Lotus 1-2-3.

[The Intentional Date Bug](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/oddity/the_intentional_date_bug/)

[Microsoft's own explanation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214058)

From now on, I think I'll justify bugs in *my* code with the same excuse.

;-)